# How do I add an image to this text?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($new_result) == 1)
        {
            if ($row['borrowingPower'] == 'mayor')
                print "<div id='verified'>This User is Verified!<div>";
        }
?>
```

In addition to the text "This User is Verified", how can I make an image display just to the right or just above the text?

ADDED TEST FILE FOR THIS WORK  http://neighborrow.com/wanted_test.php?item=116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `<img>` tag:

```
<?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($new_result) == 1)
        {
            if ($row['borrowingPower'] == 'mayor')
                print "<div id='verified'>This User is Verified! <img src='icon_ok.png' style='vertical-align: middle' alt='' /><div>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: "The user is Verified! Verified!" — that alt text could use a little work.

Comment: "This User is Verified! The user was successfully verified" — still packed with redundant/duplicate information. If the image just illustrates content that already appears in the text, just use `alt=""`.

Comment: OK then, an empty <code>alt</code> tag. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

With an [img element](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/17-images-in-html/) (note that the section on alt text is a little lacking in that article, so also see [this document](http://htmlhelp.com/feature/art3.htm)).

Comment: … and from the perspective of separation of concerns, the icon conveys information, so it is content, not presentation.

Answer (score 3):

another way to do this is adding a css class to your DIV element

CSS code:

```
.user_verified {
    background: url(../images/user_verified.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($new_result) == 1)
        {
            if ($row['borrowingPower'] == 'mayor')
                print "<div id='verified' class='user_verified'>This User is Verified!<div>";
        }
?>
```